# Declaring the name of an object using a variable

Tags: c++, class, object

So I am trying to get input from an user and then name the object of my class customer the same as the input from the user. When I do this I get the error

> "main.cpp: In function ‘void getinfo(String)’: main.cpp:34:13: error:
>   declaration of ‘customer x’ shadows a parameter   customer
>   x(firstname, lastname, account, pinnum, balance, accthist);

I need a way to customize the name of the class automatically, either by assigned variable which can be modified or by user input.

***** Update******
I do want to be straightforward. This is a school project meant to be worked on by two or three people that I am now doing solo. Below is a link to the assignment. I include this in case someone might have a better way of using my code or a better way of addressing the issue I am working to solve.

[assignemnt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8NMy2N-HFiLQ2lTSHkzZnNuVG8/view?usp=sharing)

```
void getinfo(string x){
//----------Variable Declarations--------------

    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    string account;
    int pinnum;
    double balance;
    vector <int> accthist;  


//----------Get Last Name----------------------------
    cout<<"Please enter your last name\n";
    cin>>lastname;
//----------Get First Name----------------------------
    cout<<"Please enter your first name\n";
    cin>>firstname;
//----------Get Account Number----------------------------
    cout<<"Please enter your desired account number\n";
    cin>>account;
//----------Get Pin Number----------------------------
    cout<<"Please enter your desired pin number\n";
    cin>>pinnum;
//----------Get First Deposit of $1,000.00--------------
    cout<<"Please enter your desired balance\n";
    cin>>balance;   

//----------create customer----------------------------
    customer x(firstname, lastname, account, pinnum, balance, accthist);
}



int main(){
    int choice;
    cout<<"\t\t Please enter the number corresponding to your selected action.\n\n";
    cout<<"1) Open a New Account (Minimum $1,000.00 Deposit)\t"<<"2) Close an Existing Account\n";
    cout<<"3) Make a Withdraw ($50.00 -$500.00)\t\t\t"<<"4) Make a Deposit\n";
    cout<<"5)Check Account Balance\t\t\t\t\t"<<"6) Bank Statistics Menu\n";
    cin>>choice;

    if (choice == 1){
        string test;
        cout<<"Please enter your first name";
        cin>>test;
        getinfo(test);

    }
    /*if (choice == 2){

    }
    if (choice == 3){

    }
    if (choice == 4){

    }
    if (choice == 5){

    }
    if (choice == 6){

    }
    */else cout<<"Oops!";
return 0;
}
```

HEADER FILE- functions.h

```
#include "std_lib_facilities_4.h"

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
class customer{
    private:
        string firstn;
        string lastn;
        string acct;
        int pin;
        double bal;
        vector <int> lastten;

    public:
    customer(string t1,string t2,string t3, int t4, double t5, vector <int> t6);
    void deposit(double n){};
    void withdraw (double n){};
    double get_bal(){};

};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
class stats{
    double avg_bal();       //average balance
    double total_deposits();        //sum of all account balances
    int total_cust();   //total number of customers
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
class bank{
    private:
        vector <string> allcust;

    public:
        void display_cust_account();
        bool verify_cust();
        void create_new_acct(string temp);
        void check_maintenance_fee();
        void read_cust_accounts_from_file();
        void save_cust_account_to_file();
        void make_backup_file();
        void print_stats();
};
```

Comment: Full code please. Do you have 2 variables with same name?

Comment: Assuming you are able to figure out how to do this (you can't, by the way), how exactly do you plan on referencing this dynamic variable name in your code? What do you even imagine such code might look like? It would have to be done through the `x` variable. But if you're going to use the `x` variable anyway, you might as well just make `x` the static name of your variable, since variable names are not visible at runtime.

Comment: Well I'm wondering if it could be done by using pointers and references to name the object using a 'new' function. such as `customer* p= new customer(blah,blah);` or something like that. I would ostream this customer to a database where I could tag them by firstname, lastname and social.

Comment: @claywd: That creates an object dynamically. But that doesn't choose the object's name dynamically. But you don't need to choose the object's name dynamically, because even if you could, you couldn't refer to that object name with a runtime string. Because object names only exist at compile time. Perhaps what you want is an [Associative Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)? If so, you can use [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Answer (score 1):

> "main.cpp: In function ‘void getinfo(String)’: main.cpp:34:13: error: declaration of ‘customer x’ shadows a parameter customer x(firstname, lastname, account, pinnum, balance, accthist);

Whatever you want to achieve with this code (I seriously doubt it makes any sense after fixing that simple error), it's pretty obvious what the error message says:

```
customer x(firstname, lastname, account, pinnum, balance, accthist);
      // ^
```

the variable name `x` from the line above is the same as used for the function's parameter

```
void getinfo(string x){
                 // ^
```

That's what *shadowing* actually means in this context.

---

So to fix this, you choose a different name for either of these, like

```
customer y(firstname, lastname, account, pinnum, balance, accthist);
      // ^
```

or

```
void getinfo(string y){
                 // ^
```

Comment: Still, this will be a noop

Comment: @DieterLücking To cite myself: _"Whatever you want to achieve with this code ..."_ (I've VTC the question now)

Comment: I understand the error, I included it for thoroughness not interpretation.

What I need is a way to create objects in a class... with different names and those names based on user input. Any idea on how to do that or if it is possible?

Comment: @claywd Your question is completely unclear about what you actually want to achieve: _"I need a way to customize the name of the class automatically, either by assigned variable which can be modified or by user input."_ Sorry, I don't get what you want to do.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ 

Okay in my banking program I want to open accounts with customers in them. I have included the header file containing my customer class, bank class and stats class for reference. I want to open accounts, each account linked to a customer and eventually tag the customer. 

I thought I could create objects of my customer class with all their information dynamically. When I say dynamically I mean I would call a function such as 'getinfo' and it would create the customer object named after the variable x.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move your `getInfo` function to a method inside your `customer` class.

```
class Customer
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    string account;
    int pinnum;
    double balance;
    vector <int> accthist;  
  public:
    void getInfo(void);
};

void Customer::getInfo()
{
//----------Get Last Name----------------------------
    cout<<"Please enter your last name\n";
    cin>>lastname;
//----------Get First Name----------------------------
    cout<<"Please enter your first name\n";
    cin>>firstname;
//----------Get Account Number----------------------------
    cout<<"Please enter your desired account number\n";
    cin>>account;
//----------Get Pin Number----------------------------
    cout<<"Please enter your desired pin number\n";
    cin>>pinnum;
//----------Get First Deposit of $1,000.00--------------
    cout<<"Please enter your desired balance\n";
    cin>>balance;   
}

int main(void)
{
  Customer person;

  // Print prompt and get the customer information.
  person.getInfo();

  //...
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I guess that would help but my goal is to create the object of my class dynamically, which I'm beginning to think is impossible. Using your edited code I want person to be created because the user's name is person.

Does that make sense?

Comment: To create the object dynamically, use `operator new` and a smart or unique pointer.  The architecture (organization) of your program is different than its execution.

Comment: 'customer *x= new customer(custname, account, pinnum, balance, accthist);'

Like that?